# Converting regular expressions to bash patterns

Tags: bash, regular-expression, wildcards

I have the following regular expressions and want to convert them to bash patterns.

```
itg='^[-+]?[0-9]*$'
fxp='^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$'
flp='^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$'
```

I am trying to match numeric values

```
Integral Values 1 21 144 -17

Fixed point values 3.142 0.334 .345 -7.345 -0.34345

Floating point values 3.142E-2 43.234E+3 234.345e7
```

I am using a bash script using `BRE` or `ERE`.

Comment: What is a regular-pattern?

Comment: The equivalent expressions where the special characters are put at the front and the `()` brackets are used.  E.g. `+(patterns)`.  Do people call them Glob-Patterns?  I don't know precisely.

Comment: Yes, those are known as "shell globs". Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also edit to explain if you are trying to automate this or if you want a one-off translation of these specific regular expressions. Finally, we need to know what shell you will be using because different shells have different glob patterns and capabilities and also what regex-flavor the regular expressions are using. For example, should the `+` mean "one or more" as it does in PCRE and ERE or should it mean a literal `+` character as it does in BRE?

Comment: One last thing: your first regex will also match an empty string (try `echo "" | grep -qE '^[-+]?[0-9]*$' && echo match`), your second will match even a single number. Is that really what you want? You might want to also explain what the regexes are supposed to do so we can be sure we are giving you equivalent globs.

Comment: they're "extended globs", see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean convert a regexp to a shell glob, note that not all regexp operator can be converted to shell glob operators. For instance, there's no standard glob equivalent for regexp `*`.

Some shells have extended glob operators for that though. In `zsh`, that's `#` though only when the `extendedglob` option is enabled. In ksh, the equivalent of `x*` is `*(x)`. `bash`, with the `extglob` option enabled supports a subset of ksh's extended operators: `@(...)`, `?(...)`, `*(...)` and `+(...)` only (not back references, `~(...)`, `\d`, `\s`, `{1,3}(...)`...)

ksh93's `printf` builtin can convert extended regexps to ksh globs with its `%P` format directive (`%R` does the reverse conversion from ksh glob to (ast-open flavoured) regexp).

If you're lucky, you'll be able to use the resulting glob in `bash -O extglob`:

```
$ itg='^[-+]?[0-9]*$'
$ fxp='^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$'
$ flp='^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$'
$ ksh -c 'printf "%P\n" "$@"' ksh "$itg" "$fxp" "$flp"
?([-+])*([0-9])
?([-+])*([0-9])?([.,])+([0-9])
?([-+])*([0-9])?([.,])+([0-9])?([eE]?([-+])+([0-9]))
```

Here, you're lucky, it's all regexp operators supported by `bash -O extglob`.

In any case, if you're going to use that for input validation, you'll need to change `[0-9]` to `[0123456789]` as `[0-9]` in bash (and in most of the common locales of today) matches on hundreds more characters than the 10 0123456789 ones.

Also note that your `itg` regexp matches on `-`, `+` and the empty string, and on numbers such as `019` that `bash` arithmetic evaluation for instance chokes on (as an invalid octal number).

Also note that `bash` can also do extended regexp pattern matching with its `[[ $string =~ $regexp ]]` operator or of course invoke any tool that can do regexp matching such as `grep`, `perl`, `awk`, `sed` or more advanced shells such as `zsh` or `ksh93`... After all, that's what a shell is for: run commands.

Comment: So glad to hear it.  Yuppie !